# How to use variable in pyqt MessageBox

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qmessagebox

I'm using MessageBox to get user input if data is to be added to database, but I don't know how to place my variables inside the actual message. MessageBox function looks like this:

```
def message(self, par_1, par_2):
    odp = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Information', "No entry. Would you like to add it to DB?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
    if odp == QMessageBox.Yes:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Function is called like this:

```
self.message(autor_firstname, autor_lastname)
```

I tried adding:

```
odp.setDetailText(par_1, par_2)
```

But it didn't work as expected. Additionally I have problem when user clicks "No". Program crashes instead of returning to main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs on QMessageBox::question](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question), the return value is the button that was clicked. Using the static method `QMessageBox::question` limits how you can customize the `QMessageBox`. Instead, create an instance of `QMessageBox` explicitly, call `setText`, `setInformativeText`, and `setDetailedText` as needed. Note that your arguments also do not match what is needed for `setDetailedText`. Those docs are [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#detailedText-prop). I think your code should look something like this.

```
def message(self, par_1, par_2):

    # Create the dialog without running it yet
    msgBox = QMessageBox()

    # Set the various texts
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Information")
    msgBox.setText("No entry. Would you like to add it to the database")
    detail = "%s\n%s" % (par_1, par_2) # formats the string with one par_ per line.
    msgBox.setDetailedText(detail) 

    # Add buttons and set default
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)     

    # Run the dialog, and check results   
    bttn = msgBox.exec_()
    if bttn == QMessageBox.Yes:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: That makes sense, I've added this code but program crashes. message function is called but program exits with Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: I found that program was crashing at:
`msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)`
I've changed it to:
`msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)`
and it started working.

Comment: @HyperQBE Glad it worked. I'll update the answer to reflect your comment. Sorry about the error. I should have mentioned that it wasn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

This can also solve your problem:

```
def message(self, par_1, par_2):
    # Create the dialog without running it yet
    msgBox = QMessageBox()

    # Set the various texts
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Information")
    msgBox.setText("No entry for '"+str(par_1)+" "+str(par_2)+"'.Would you like to add it to the database")
    

   # Add buttons and set default
   msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
   msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)     

   # Run the dialog, and check results   
   bttn = msgBox.exec_()
   if bttn == QMessageBox.Yes:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Not the use of string concatenation on line 6.